# Cant see battery status in iphone x after fixing the launch image ionic v1

Tags: ionic-framework, iphone-x

I am using Ionic v1 for my hybrid application. In order to support iphone x view I added to 
info.plist:

```
   <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
   <string>CDVLaunchScreen</string>
```

and viewport-fit=cover in the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">
```

The problem is after adding this properties I can't see battery status and time on iphone x and higher

[image]

Comment: try: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar

Answer (score 0):

Found answer by adding this property to info.plist:

```
  <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
  <true/>
```

Comment: How you add something to your app-info.plist ?Everything I add to that , deleted for me after I do ' ionic cordova prepare ios '